# Lightweight online opensource css editor - php

Tags: php, looking-for-a-script, open-source

I'm looking for an online **opensource** editor for **css files**. It should have **syntax highlighting**. Also it should be **easily integratable** within php code.

**Edit:** I need something like `textarea` that highlights my css code. And i want to add it to my website so i can change my css from everyplace.

Comment: going to add an answer, but i'm not entirely sure what you mean. do you mean an editor that gets integrated into a website (like the one you wrote your question in) ? that allows you to edit content and also css or are you looking for an editor that allows you to edit css that is in the same document as php code ?

Comment: Check my answer I provided a demo in the update to an online open source editor with syntax highlighting which you can integrate into a web app

Answer (score 0):

Without a lot of research I will go ahead and assume that there is no javascript based editor that will syntax highlight code that you could integrate into a website.
As a lightweight editor that syntax highlights and lets you edit css and php i would recommend [notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/). It will syntax highlight a lot of languages (html/php/css are among them). But there are many others.

Comment: I've edited the question, so now it better explain what i want

Comment: while it is possible to implement something that lets you edit css files or even html documents online i wouldn't recommend trying. Since there is very little use to something like that, i am fairly confident that no such thing exists in a downloadable form.  I would always recommend editing the css offline and trying it out before uploading (if you have a css file and an html file you can just load it into a browser locally to see how it looks without even needing a webserver).

Answer (score 0):

You should download and use [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/) which is the editor that MailChimp and many other major companies use, it is open source and combined with the [syntax highlighter plugin](http://code.google.com/p/ckeditor-syntaxhighlight/) it's the perfect tool for integrating into your own custom web application to edit CSS and other files

Updating my answer

Ckeditor has syntax highlighting built in see the [demo here](https://dev.ckeditor.com/prefs/pygments)